# How was this question answered after it was closed?

Tags: bug, answers, closed-questions

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43117860/1968) on SO.

At the time of writing, it was asked 45 minutes ago <sub><sup>*(12:27:48Z)*</sup></sub>. It was closed 40 minutes ago <sub><sup>*(12:32:42Z)*</sup></sub>. And user Gio posted an answer 21 minutes ago <sub><sup>*(12:51:20Z)*</sup></sub>.

*What?*

Usually when a question is closed, no more answers can be posted, *even when somebody was already writing an answer at the time*. And the question wasn’t closed, reopened, re-closed either: it remained closed.

So what happened?

Comment: *"even when somebody was already writing an answer at the time"* Are you sure about that? If I remember correctly, it is still possible to post the answer, but you'll get a notification that the question was closed.

Comment: @Tom If you get the notification, then the button's supposed to be disabled. However, if websockets aren't working for you or are blocked, you won't even get the notification. Likewise, I believe I've seen someone mentioning re-enabling the button through the dev tools will allow you to submit.

Comment: @Kendra Hmm. I knew about the grace period but *20 minutes*? Seemed unlikely. I now see that the grace period is in fact 4 hours. Huh.